# No module named 'fbchat'

Tags: python, chat

So im new at python and programming and trying to work out the basic of `fbchat` which seems very manageable but I keep getting this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbchat'` I'm 100% sure that I've installed `fbchat` by using:

```
pip install fbchat
```

and have also tried

```
git clone https://github.com/carpedm20/fbchat.git
pip install fbchat
```

Either way I still get the same error.

This is the code:

```py
import fbchat

session = fbchat.Session.login("<xxxxxx@hotmail.com>", "<xxxx>")

print("Own id: {}".format(session.user.id))


session.user.send_text("Hi You!")


session.logout()
```

I really hope that you can help me with this problem, thank you for your time

[image: Proof that fbchat is downloaded]

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right pip ? If you are using `python3` you should be using `pip3` instead of pip. Another possibility could be you have installed in outside the venv

Comment: check these `pip -V` and `which python` or `which python3` that you used

Comment: Hey Arun, 
Im using pyton3.8, so I just deleted the fbchat download that I've downloaded earlier and installed it with pip3, and I still get the error. I don't know what you mean by outside the venv..

Comment: hey @0xF4D3C0D3,
I've just run pip _V and it printed out:

pip 20.1 from /Users/userA/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Comment: and what's the result of this?

import sys; print(sys.executable)

Comment: @0xF4D3C0D3 the result og this is:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8

Comment: @Sedar, yes. you installed a package with python3.7 and now you are using python3.8, not python3.7 in which the package is installed

Comment: so try this out, python3.8 -m pip install fbchat

Comment: @0xF4D3C0D3. Im such an idiot you're completely right now when I try to run it with python3.7 test.py it finally imports the module fbchat. Thank you very much! Appreciate it.

Comment: @0xF4D3C0D3, now it gives me a new error: 

AttributeError: module 'fbchat' has no attribute 'Session'

does it have something to do with my pip?

Comment: what's your python script file name? isn't it fbchat? or are there any file which is named as fbchat in your directory in which the python script is executed

Comment: If there are any file having name fbchat, when you import fbchat, the fbchat package you wanted won't be imported rather the file having name fbchat will be imported unintentionally

Comment: my script is called test123.py I have no file called fbchat in my directory

Comment: @Sedar, how about this? from fbchat import Session and Session.login(...)

Comment: @Sedar, Oh nevermind the above answer, check this out https://github.com/carpedm20/fbchat/issues/525 you are using unreleased version

Comment: @0xF4D3C0D3 okay something happened now! it tried to log in but failed!!! Excitiiiiing

Comment: @0xF4D3C0D3 well it says login failed check email/password. I might be able to find a solution on another thread. If not I might return. Thank you so so much for your time and help!

Comment: good luck Sedar :D

Answer (score 1):

First check your pip version is using desired python or not

```
pip --version
```

If not then you should use different pip version for an example if you're using python3 then install using pip3

If there's no issue of version then try to use virtual environment

create one using

```
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install fbchat
```

Refer this link for os wise instructions
https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Install using `Python3.8 -m pip install fbchat`

Comment: hey @sharan sharma My pip version is: pip 19.2.3 
and I hav just tried to create a virtual environment, which successfully installed fbchat-1.9.6.

I went to my dictionary with my fbchat code is and tried to run it again... and the result is the same --> no module named fbchat.

Comment: When you did pip version what version of python it showed you like in my case

pip3 --version
pip 19.2.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

python3.8 --version
Python 3.8.1

both of your versions should match

Comment: It show me:
pip 20.1 from /Users/<myaccount>/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Comment: Okay so you're using python3.7 tell me your python version too through which you are running your file

Comment: Python3 -m pip install fbchat try this one

Comment: I thought I had python3.8 so I've always typed python3.8 script.py

Comment: Do this Python3.8 -m pip install fbchat

Comment: Yes I have done that now and it says Requirement already satisfied: fbchat in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.9.6)

Comment: Deactivate your virtual environment if you're using and do source again

Comment: I don't know how to deactivate it so I just quit terminal and opened again and ran my script python3.8 test123.py

  File "test123.py", line 4, in <module>
    session = fbchat.Session.login("<email>", "<password>")
AttributeError: module 'fbchat' has no attribute 'Session'

Comment: Your module not found issue is resolved now read fbchat module docs for resolve these further issues

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!!